# how to self terminate a spot instance once the task is done

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I do not see that there is way to specify shutdownBehavior for spot instances. It only gives option to configure interruption behavior.

I would like to know, how to i terminate spot instance from within, once the task is done. is "shutdown -h now" is enough ?

Comment: How are you running the task, via a script on the instance? How does the instance know when your task is done.

Comment: You should use `Lambda` for such things, example pattern: [Terminate EC2 with S3 and Lambda](http://rahuldhumal.com/techblog/index.php/2018/10/01/aws-lambda-to-terminate-instances/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a spot instance can self-terminate with `sudo shutdown now -h`. (I just tried it, it worked!)

I notice that the Spot Request hangs around, with a status of *instance-terminated-by-user*, so you might want to delete it.

An alternative method would be for the instance to call `describe-spot-instance-requests` to discover its spot request ID (`sir-`) and then call `cancel-spot-instance-requests`. That would also terminate the instance, and would also cancel the spot request.